Power Apps Canvas App: Can't Search Newly Added Data in Excel Table with Filter, but Search Works
I'm working on a Power Apps Canvas app and have created both a table and a form screen. Both are connected to the same Excel data source, SacStokTable, which initially had 2000 rows of data. I configured the app to automatically generate a Power Apps ID when adding new records.
In the search box, I have this filter to search for values in the "Malzeme" column:
Set(filterSacStokYonetimi, SacStokYonetimiArama2.Value);
In the table's Items property, I applied the following formula to filter the data based on the search text:
Filter(SacStokTable, Lower(Text(Trim(filterSacStokYonetimi))) in Malzeme)
This worked perfectly and I could search within the 2000 rows of data based on the Malzeme column.
However, after adding a new material through the form using the "New" button, I checked the Excel table and confirmed that the new material was added with a Power Apps ID. The problem is that I can no longer search for the newly added material using the above Filter formula, but I can find it if I use the Search function like this:
Search(SacStokTable, filterSacStokYonetimi, Malzeme)
The issue is that using Search finds the newly added data, but when using Filter, it doesn't show the new entries. The search works for new data but doesn’t return the existing 2000 rows when filtering.
Why does this happen, and how can I ensure that both the new and old data are searchable using Filter?

Okay That's weird but it worked.
I realized that:
Filter(SacStokTable, Lower(Text(filterSacStokYonetimi)) in Text(Malzeme))
Filter(SacStokTable, Lower(Text(filterSacStokYonetimi)) in Malzeme)
commands return different results. The first one is returning previously added records before the table connection. The second one is returning new added records by form submit.
The fields in the form are set to text format.
The Excel table’s columns are also in text format.
I haven’t changed any settings manually, but everything appears to be in text format, and I don’t know why its working.
